# How to run a function based on the width of the page without scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a sidebar which I want to move to the bottom on a width < 1000px.

I use:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($('#page').innerWidth() < 1000) {
    jQuery(".sidebar").remove().insertAfter(jQuery(".page-content"));
  } else {
    jQuery(".sidebar").remove().insertBefore(jQuery(".page-content"));
  }
});

if ($('#page').innerWidth() < 1000) {
    jQuery(".sidebar").remove().insertAfter(jQuery(".page-content"));
}
else {
    jQuery(".sidebar").remove().insertBefore(jQuery(".page-content"));
}
```

this works well but on browsers with a scrollbar the sidebar shows on the right side around the 1006 / 1008 px.

I must disable the scrollbar with the code. How can I do that?

Comment: If its the screen size that triggers the moving of sidebar, then why not achieve this via a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: @Rushikumar how can I move the sidebar to the bottom with media query? it must be show after the page-content

Comment: Here is an `@media` example: https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yvMJaG